# React.render makes empty subcomponent in jsdom

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, jsdom

I'm playing with React in node using jsdom.  When I try to render a component that contains another component that has content, it'll fail to render the subcomponents content.  For example,

```js
var React = require('react');
var SubComponent = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return React.createElement("div");
  }
});

var TestComponent = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    /* JSX would look like this:
      <div>
        <p>regular tag</p>
        <SubComponent>sub component</SubComponent>
      </div>
    */
    return React.createElement(
      "div", {},
      React.createElement("p", {}, "regular tag"),
      React.createElement(SubComponent, {}, "sub component")
    );
  }
});

global.document = require('jsdom').jsdom('<!doctype html><html><body></body></html>');
global.window = document.parentWindow;
global.navigator = window.navigator;
```

React.render(React.createElement(TestComponent), global.document.body)
console.log(document.body.innerHTML);

This will log the following markup to the console:

```html
<div data-reactid=".zf2pciql8g">
  <p data-reactid=".zf2pciql8g.0">regular tag</p>
  <div data-reactid=".zf2pciql8g.1"></div>
</div>
```

Note the `<p>` tag has its content, but the `<SubComponent>` tag was changed into an empty div.

Why doesn't the div have "sub component" as its inner content? I'm just learning React, so am I doing something obviously dumb here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `React.createElement(SubComponent, {}, "sub component")`, you are passing `"sub component"` to `SubComponent` via `this.props.children`. However, in `SubComponent`, you're not using `this.props.children` and just rendering an empty div via `React.createElement("div")`.

A simple fix would be to pass `this.props.children` to the div you're creating in the `render` method of `SubComponent`:

```js
var SubComponent = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return React.createElement("div", {}, this.props.children);
  }
});
```

See [Type of the Children props](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/children-props-type.html) for more information about `this.props.children`.